# Xcode crashes when dragging UIElement to model

Tags: ios, xcode5

When I attempt to drag a UIButton to my ViewController.m (control + drag), Xcode crashes. I have tried unchecking the "Use Autolayout" box, but I am still having the same issue. I am using OS X 10.9.4 and Xcode 5.1.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds awful and it should not be happening. However, there is an easy solution: do not do that. Control-dragging from the Interface Builder canvas to your code is completely unnecessary; you can do everything you need to entirely by working in the code and in IB separately.

I realize that for you this is not a solution ("why am I crashing?") but rather a workaround, but it's a perfectly good workaround and will allow you to move on with your work.

Comment: The only reasons for dragging from IB to code are to form an outlet or to form an action. Since this is a button, I'm guessing it's an action. This section of my book explains how make an action, giving many alternatives other than dragging from IB into code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Everything seems back to normal now. All I had to do was restart my Mac. Also, what book are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste in the link! This is the section I was suggesting: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_action_connections. It's great to know that this crashing behavior was so easily escapable. Sometimes people have to reinstall Xcode and other unpleasant things...

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem Ctrl-Dragging from a map view inside a prototype cell to the view controller that the prototype cell subclassed from. I mistakenly had an old outlet reference left on the map view, and after removing and saving the change, Xcode no longer repeated the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one version of XCode on your machine?  I had the same issue and think there was a conflict because I had XCode 5 and 6 installed.  I deleted 5 with appCleaner and got rid of all the extra files.  Everything was working after that.

If you only have XCode 5, I would try a clean install.